# Can't find files downloaded from sftp

Tags: ftp, putty, sftp

I can't find the files I "get" from an sftp server.  I'm using Windows and running sftp.exe from the [PuTTY suite](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).  When I type lpwd to see the local directory, it shows it but I never see the files I used "get" on

Answer (score 2):

Look at

```
C:\Users\_your_user_name\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY
```

Answer (score 1):

`lpwd` just prints the current local working directory; it doesn't show directory contents.  Use `!dir` for that.

Comment: Thanks.. but the file isn't in that directory either